# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, After copying pathname

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
x_train = []
for i in range(1, 4): 
    base_dir = f'/Users/name/Desktop/cancer_data/stage_1_png' #pathname that I copy-pasted
    files = os.listdir(base_dir)
    for file in tqdm(files):
        img = imread(base_dir+file)
        x_train.append(img)
x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_train.shape
```

I copy-pasted the pathname from the folder I want to extract images from, This same exact code was working before, but now I get the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/name/Desktop/cancer_data/stage_1_png'
```

I held down the Option key whilst in the folder, and clicked "copyPathname" (on mac). So it cannot possibly be a non-existent path/folder.

Comment: We cannot validate if the path is correct or not, so this kind of questions are not answerable.

Comment: I wrote in the question title that I copy-pasted the pathname? Does it help you to say that I held down the Option key whilst in the directory(on Mac), and clicked "copyPathname" from where I wanted to extract images from? How could that possibly be a non-existent path?

Answer (score 0):

check the filename again.
I think it should be **stage_1.png** instead of *stage_1_png*

Comment: I held down the Option key whilst in the folder, and clicked "copyPathname" (on mac)

Answer (score 0):

It is a relative path. I prefer to use r"".
`shift` +  `right click` on the image file. You will find a `copy path` option and use that instead of path.

Comment: yes, I am using Mac, so I did a similar thing, I held down the Option key whilst in the folder, and clicked "copyPathname"

Comment: I am using mac, so shift + right click on the image file, did not do anything